# Are we trying to motivate ourselves by combinating safe stressful situations with pleasure regards?

Tags: learning, stress, evolutionary-psychology, fear, reward

When there's a stressful situation with no real danger like we need a hug  or we stress-eat. Are we trying to develop in our brain networks a fear of actually dangerous situations instead of fear of situation when we're safe and have what we need?

Or what is the reason behind the evolution of this phenomenon?

Some more examples of the followed phenomenon:

- Antidepressants are part of the official treatment plan of depression or [PTSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posttraumatic_stress_disorder#Prevention).
- When we cause ourselves an injury, we pat our wounds.
- [People crave sweets after exercise](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/workout-craving-dessert-study_us_57a49a0ee4b056bad2152ec3) (might seem like an escape from a predator to our body)
- [Stress-eating](http://www.webmd.com/diet/stop-emotional-eating)

Could those be examples of it?

Comment: No data to support, but my initial suspicion would be that we are conditioned to those responses as children, when our mothers hug / feed us when we cry. We then learn that those stimuli are associated with the reduction of stress, and continue to seek them in adult life.

Comment: I like that idea

Comment: Is there any reason to assume that we subconsciously associate regular stress with grievous danger? Every stress needs relief. but why do we use the relief mechanisms that we do? Maybe a doctor will be better qualified to answer that. For example, hugs release oxytocin in our body.

Comment: @user140259 Oh, so you suppose we calm ourselves after a stressful situation to stop the body mechanisms of starting the "maximum moder"? That seems nice!